# child process spawn python node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am trying to call a python script using node.js child process.

JS

```
console.log('Hello World!')

const path = require('path')
const {spawn} = require('child_process')
/**
   * Run python script, pass in `-u` to not buffer console output
   * @return {ChildProcess}
*/
function runScript(){
   return spawn('python', [
      "-u",
      path.join(__dirname, 'pythonscript.py'),
     "--foo", "some value for foo",
   ]);
}
const subprocess = runScript()


// print output of script
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
   console.log(`data:${data}`);
});
subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
   console.log(`error:${data}`);
});
subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
   console.log("Closed");
});
```

python

```
mydict =    {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "licensePlate" : "O XXX YYY",
  "year" : 1964,
  "insured": {
                'lastname' : 'Snow', 
                'firstname' : 'John', 
                'adress' : 'Holiday street, 4 - Paradise'
             }
}
print(mydict)
```

The purpose is to be able to use the dictionary created by the python code in javascript.

But a this step I am faced to an error which is provided here below.

```
Hello World!
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn python',
  path: 'python',
  spawnargs: [
    '-u',
    '/mnt/c/Users/xxxx/javascript/pythonscript.py',
    '--foo',
    'some value for foo'
  ]
}
```

can you help me with this? I work with Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10, I don't know if this information is relevant or not...

Comment: I think `ENOENT` is node saying it cannot find the `python` executable. Does it work if you replace `'python'` with a full path? And you do know that JavaScript can work directly with a JSON dictionary?

Comment: @James replacing `python` by the full path does not work unfortunately. What I provide as example here is the result of the python script (my real python script scan a QR code and return as result a dictionary that looks like the one provided here).

Comment: What is the result of typing `python -v` in a terminal? The problem/solution stated by james was the first thing that came to my mind. The python executable cant be found. Seems like from the path, that your are on WSL, theck if you can execute any pathon commands from there.